# Can this CSS layout be achieved in IBM portlet?

Tags: css, portlet

I am using the IBM portlet development portal, and the current configuration is three columns,like this:

[image: Three column layout]

Now I need to add a picture like this (green color):

[image]

Can this be achieved? How would I achieve this?

Comment: is it a portlet? then you'll want to look at Theme Development

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout template and add it to your page in  the **Type of Page**  section of **Page properties** page.